# How to Display name without extension and convert hyphen into space in php?

Tags: php, image, directory, pull

I want to display Full-Name.jpg as Full Name. How do i do that? Following is the code i have

```
<?php
    $folder = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/img/');
    while($file = readdir($folder)){
        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
            echo '<div class="wrap"><a href="img/'.$file.'"><img src="img/'.$file.'"/>';
            echo '<p>'.$file.'</p></a></div>
            ';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the filename using http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php like so :

```
$filenameonly=pathinfo($file)['filename'];
```

and you can replace characters using http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php like so :

```
$filenamewithoutdash=str_replace('-','',$filenameonly);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$folder = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/img/');
        while($file = readdir($folder)){
            if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
                echo '<div class="wrap"><a href="img/'.$file.'"><img src="img/'.$file.'"/>';                
                $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file);
                echo '<p>'.str_replace('-', ' ', $withoutExt).'</p></a></div>';
            }
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed it into the following to get it working

```
  <?php
      $folder = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/img/');
      while($file = readdir($folder)){
          if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
              echo '<div class="wrap"><a href="img/'.$file.'"><img src="img/'.$file.'"/>';
              $file = substr($file, 0, (strlen($file))-(strlen(strrchr($file, '.'))));
                      $file = str_replace('-', ' ', $file);
              echo '<p>'.$file.'</p></a></div>
              ';
          }
      }
  ?>
```

can it be as a function and then call it with a short code or something?